# Access value of control that is created at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem:

I create a TextBox at run time in a panel that is contained in a Wizard.

I want to access the value that the client will insert to this textbox.

I wrote this code to do that:

```
TextBox _txt = Panel1.FindControl(txtArray[i].ID) as TextBox;
```

But I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

That means that FindControl didn't find this control by its id.

This is the code for the creation of the textbox in runtime:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= loop; i++)
{
     txtArray[i] = new TextBox();
     txtArray[i].ID = "txt4Name" + i;
}
```

Can someone help me to find the error?

Comment: Where do you add the text boxes to the panel? In what method is the creation code? Are you recreating the text boxes _every time_ the page loads?

Comment: no, i created the texbox as response of number of textboxs 'from the client'

Comment: OK. So you are not adding them to the panel. How is the panel `FindControl` method supposed to find a control that was not added to it?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to access the TextBox, you already have it in your array. No need to use FindControl.

```
TextBox _txt = txtArray[i];
```

However, I suspect ypu might have another error here. Are you sure it is added to the panel, also on PostBack ?